# Hibernate query date compare on year and month only

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I need to grab some records from a table which has a Column `birthDate` which is a `Date`(without time). I need to filter records by comparing against year and month only. 
For example I want all the users born on March of 1990. The day doesn't matter.

How do you handle it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `from Entity where to_char(birthDate,'YYYY/MM') = '1990/03'` 
this will work for HQL

Comment: Is important to note here that this is a Oracle Function. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm 
In my case with MySql this does't work.

Answer (score 7):

you may try this

```
 select * from table where month(birthdate)=03 and year(birthdate)=1990
```

Comment: Is this PL/SQL? I'm searching for a hibernate solution(HQL), but If I can't find one then I'll have to use database specific one.

Comment: The equivalent of using month() and year() functions would be: "from Entity where year(birthDate)=:year and month(birthDate)=:month" and, afterwards, bind :year and :month parameters using query's setString(yourDate's value).

Answer (score 1):

it is a HQL query that works for me

```
from Person as p where year(p.birthDate)=year(:bDate) and month(p.birthDate)=month(:bDate)"
```

the type of bDate is Date, you can pass Integer

```
from Person as p where year(p.birthDate)=:bYear and month(p.birthDate)=:bMonth
```