# Hibernate query date compare month only

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I need to grab some records from a MySQL table which has a Column `posted_date` which is a `Timestamp`. I need to filter records by comparing against month only. For example I want all the records posted this month only.

I tried as given in this link [Hibernate query date compare on year and month only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973700/hibernate-query-date-compare-on-year-and-month-only)

But I get following error

```
line 1:106: unexpected token: to_char
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:769)
```

How to compare only with month in HQL by taking month as parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use MONTH(...) HQL function like this:

```
select so from SomeObject so where MONTH(so.date) = MONTH(:date)
```

or (simple but not database agnostic - works with Oracle/PostgreSQL/H2)

```
select so from SomeObject so where TO_CHAR(so.date, 'MM') = :month_as_string
```

Comment: `from SomeObject so where MONTH(so.date) = :date` worked fine., Thank you.

Comment: If it helps you, please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Way 2 is not working! 
Error: 'TO_CHAR' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Lê Công Tuấn Vũ - Worth to mention the second way is not database agnostic. It works with Oracle/PostgreSQL/H2. You can read more about [HQL Date Formats here](http://www.coding-dude.com/wp/hibernate/hql-current-date/).