# How to convert Month-Year to date in HQL/Grails?

Tags: oracle, grails, hql

This query is working in database

```
select to_date(a.year || a.month, 'YYYYMM') as dates from table a
```

but not working in Grails as HQL. Giving an error as "unexpected token". 
How do I use this query in HQL/Grails?

As example I have `month` & `year` column. I need to show this as `date` in new column.

Above `to_date(a.year || a.month, 'YYYYMM') as dates` works fine in oracle database but it doesn't work in HQL in grails where I'm using as

`executeQuery("select to_date(a.year || a.month, 'YYYYMM') as dates from table a")` but this one is not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973700/hibernate-query-date-compare-on-year-and-month-only first link in google...

Comment: I have 2 column in db as month & year which I need to convert as date. This link has no solution for me. Whatever if you don't have ability to give answer then why you have given negative

Comment: To concat string you need to use: concat(a.year, a.month) instead of a.year || a.month.
Why negative? You didn't provide logs, versions and etc.

Comment: I'm using Grails 3 and Oracle 11g as DB. I have edited answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

HQL is only good if you have modeled your database table. If you really want to use this exact query, go for native SQL instead of HQL:

```
MyController {

    Sql groovySql // package: groovy.sql

    def myAction() {

        def results = groovySql.rows("SELECT 'thisIsNativeSqlQuery'");
        // do something with your results;

    }
}
```

If you have modeled this table already (has Domain class) you can just fetch them all with `YourDomain.list()` and make a getter method that forms your date from the format you have:

```
Date toDate() {
​    return Date.parse("yyyyMM", "201808")​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
}
```

or have transient field that does this for you, it all depends on your use case

Comment: Thanks a lot. But native SQL is also not working to make date from month and year. I need to use that data to View page by a variable.

Comment: you mean, you need to `render()` a view depending on the results you get from database? Please update intro post with your grails version and exactly what are you trying to do here

Comment: Change HQL to SQL and this query will run and you will get your result. Instead of `executeQuery()` use `rows()` on an injected Sql service, like in the code example i posted, which will then perform native sql query instead of HQL.